# How would I link external libraries to a cpp file through Emacs

Tags: c++, emacs, linker, glfw

I use the Emacs text editor for editing my files, and have been looking into using OpenGL in my programs. However, I have had trouble including the GLFW header into my program.

Here is my code for the `#include` statements and essentially test if the files linked properly, which comes from the hyperlink later on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  glewExperimental = true;
  if(!glfwInit())
    {
      cout << "Failed to initialize" << endl;
      return -1;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

I hit `M-x compile` then `g++ file.cpp -lglut -lGL -lGLEW -lGLU -o file.out` and get the following error

```
g++ anotherGL.cpp -lglut -lGL -lGLEW -lGLU -o anotherGL.out
anotherGL.cpp:5:10: fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
 #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I followed the instructions for downloading the OpenGL tutorial page, under the section Building on Linux, but the instructions diverge after it moves on to the section where the packages are linked to the IDE.

(http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/)

Is there a `M-x` command I can use in place of what I have to perform the link?

Comment: Did you install the appropriate -dev packages on your machine? That's usually the ones containing the include files. Or are you on windows?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I did. There were several videos on YouTube that I found that installed the same packages. The problem I'm having is using the files as they are meant to be.

Comment: On all the linux distros I've used installing the dev packages through the packet manager will also add the headers to the default include search path for the compiler. But if that's not the case you can always specify the include directory manually by using `g++ -L/path/to/libs -I/path/to/includes`

Comment: this has nothing to do with emacs, you just haven't added the appropriate include directories to your compilation command -- `M-x compile` is just running that command in a shell -- you should have see same problems compiling from a shell

Comment: I do not know which directories to add with the `M-x compile`. I listed what extensions I was using in the body of my question @pickle rick

Comment: the point I was making was -- if the compilation command runs in your shell, it will run in `M-x compile` -- not trying to diagnose your compilation command.  But, just search for the library and the path to it, in your case the path to the directory containing `GLFW` by the looks of

Answer (score 0):

On "debian" and "red hat" systems, the include file `GLFW/glfw3.h` is under `/usr/include` a la `/usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h`. Your include statement is correct as `/usr/include` is implicitly searched by `gcc/g++`. You've just missed installing the glfw development package. On "debian" or apt-based systems this is in `libglfw3-dev`. On "red hat" or rpm based systems this is `glfw-devel`. You may also need to add the flag `-lglfw` to your compile command.